# About override ProcessCMDKey in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I want my app to respond to left arrow and right arrow key.
So I wrote

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
```

When I click Ctrl on the left side of the keyboard,
this function will be called, and the value of keyData is

```
keyData = LButton | ShiftKey | Control
```

Why is that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The debugger gets confused by the declaration of the Keys enum.  Which looks like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum Keys {
    LButton = 1,
    ShiftKey = 0x10,
    ControlKey = 0x11,
    Control = 0x20000,
    // And lots more
}
```

With the [Flags] attribute turned on, the debugger visualizer tries to show the values of the individual bits in `keyData`.  You pressed the Control key, Keys.ControlKey, whose value is 0x11.  The Control flag is turned on because of that so keyData = 0x20011.

So the debugger interprets 0x20011 as bits and makes it 0x20000 | 0x00010 | 0x00001.  Which turns into "LButton | ShiftKey | Control".  There isn't any good way to make it smarter, other than by using `(int)keyData` in the debugger expression.  The fundamental issue is the [Flags] attribute on the enum, it is only somewhat appropriate but the vast majority of Keys enum values are not flag values.